# More than 1 Component for injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm trying to fully get the dependency injection mechanism, and the functionality of the IoC container.
I created a simple project with an interface, and its implementations:

```
public interface Animal {
    public void makeSound();
}

@Component
public class Dog implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Woof woof");
    }
}

@Component
public class Cat implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Meow meow");
    }
}
```

Object of *Animal* interface is being used and autowired in another class, and all is then being initialized in Main:

```
@Repository
public class Shelter {
    private Animal animal;

    @Autowired
    public Shelter(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public void doTheThing() {
        animal.makeSound();
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
        Shelter shelter = context.getBean(Shelter.class);
        Shelter anotherShelter = context.getBean(Shelter.class);
        shelter.doTheThing();
        anotherShelter.doTheThing();
    }
}
```

Now, without **@Primary** annotation on one of the implementations of the *Animal* interface compilation throws an error, because Spring doesn't know which implementation to use. I understand this.
But now I am wondering, how can I inject different implementations to *shelter* and *anotherShelter* field "*private Animal animal*" (via an injection through constructor of course)? Is it even possible? In other words: I want to make *shelter* to use implementation of *Dog*, and *anotherShelter* the implementation of *Cat*.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Name your instances and inject them by name into the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @Qualifier annotation, and specify the name of the implementation (starting with lower case), in your sitaution "cat" / "dog"!